# QML How to dynamically chage the Color of a TextArea?

Tags: qml

Here is the code for my test APP:

```
TextAreaStyle{
    id: loggerStyle
    textColor: "#00ff88";
    backgroundColor: "#000000";
}

TextArea {
    id: taLog
    readOnly: true
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height - labelTitle.height - btnTest.height - 2*v_AIR
    x: 0
    y: labelTitle.height + v_AIR
    style: loggerStyle
    font.family: "Helvetica";
    font.pointSize: 16;
    font.bold: true
    function logError(msg){
        loggerStyle.textColor = "#FF0000"
        taLog.text = taLog.text + "\n" + msg
    }
    function logMessage(msg){
        loggerStyle.textColor = "#FFFFFF"
        taLog.text = taLog.text + "\n" + msg
    }
    function logSuccess(msg){
        loggerStyle.textColor = "#00FF00"
        taLog.text = taLog.text + "\n" + msg
    }
}
```

When I try to run this code I get all of these messages:

```
file:///opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Private/Style.qml:52: ReferenceError: __control is not defined
file:///opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/ScrollViewStyle.qml:56: ReferenceError: __control is not defined
file:///opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/TextAreaStyle.qml:80: TypeError: Cannot read property 'enabled' of null
file:///opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/TextAreaStyle.qml:77: TypeError: Cannot read property 'enabled' of null
file:///opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/TextAreaStyle.qml:68: ReferenceError: __control is not defined
file:///opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ScrollView.qml:354: TypeError: Cannot read property 'padding' of null
file:///opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ScrollView.qml:353: TypeError: Cannot read property 'padding' of null
file:///opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ScrollView.qml:352: TypeError: Cannot read property 'padding' of null
file:///opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ScrollView.qml:351: TypeError: Cannot read property 'padding' of null
file:///opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/TextArea.qml:906: TypeError: Cannot read property '__selectionHandle' of null
file:///opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/TextArea.qml:942: TypeError: Cannot read property '__cursorHandle' of null
```

And no style is applied to my text area.

So what is the correct way to dynamically change the color that I use to write messages to a TextArea?

Comment: Why doesn't changing directly [`textColor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textarea.html#textColor-prop) work for you?

Comment: It does. However I had read when styling a TextArea I should use TextAreaStyle so I was using that. Anyways. Changing textColor changes the color for all text. Turns out HMTL rich text was the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to do what I want with this code:

```
TextArea {
    id: taLog
    readOnly: true
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height - labelTitle.height - btnTest.height - 2*v_AIR
    textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
    x: 0
    y: labelTitle.height + v_AIR
    style: TextAreaStyle{
        backgroundColor: "#000000";
    }
    font.family: "Helvetica";
    font.pointSize: 16;
    font.bold: true
    function logError(msg){
        logNew(msg,"#FF0000");
    }
    function logMessage(msg){
        logNew(msg,"#FFFFFF");
    }
    function logSuccess(msg){
        logNew(msg,"#00FF00");
    }
    function logNew(msg, color){
        msg = "<p style='color: " + color +  ";' >" + msg + "</p>"
        taLog.text = taLog.text + msg
    }
}
```

I basially told it that the text would be HTML and that I the different messages have different colors.